# Wordpress system (hardware) requirements?

Tags: performance

Question: what requirements are for wordpress site? CPU, RAM, network speed, etc? I understand that it varies by number of users and number of plugins, etc, but perhaps anyone knows anything or there is any table that roughly states this?

Context: I have touched Wordpress sites several times, have set up one site myself (btw, all these sites run on VM, not a dedicated server), but I got an idea (and also people told me this too) that these wordpress(?) sites were quite slow. Slow for users, and even slower when using admin panel. It really takes some time for pages to load, and I expect from a basic small tiny website, that it should load ultra-sonic-super-fast, if not, at least just fast.

I haven't added any crazy SEO or whatever plugins, although there are some plugins (around 10), of course.

I have couple ideas: Maybe I need more expensive hosting virtual machine plan? Or maybe storing database in ram and not in hdd would help (backups would go to hdd then)(but then, at work we use DB's stored in hdd, and if query isn't super-big, everything runs smoothly)?

Maybe there are some tools that would tell which part of system is a bottleneck?

If this is basically a wordpress issue, then are there some other systems, like joomla, etc. that would have better performance?

Answer (score -1):

**System Requirements
MainWP Requires the following to work correctly:**

WordPress 3.6 or greater
WordPress Memory Limit 64MB or more

PHP version 5.3 or greater (PHP 5.6 or greater recommended)

PHP Safe Mode Disabled

PHP Max Execution Time 30 seconds or more

PHP Memory Limit 128MB or more

cURL Library Enabled

cURL Timeout 300 seconds or more

MySQL version 5.0 or greater

Not required but helpful

A memory limit of at least 512MB will help the syncing a lot (memory_limit in php.ini) – Dashboard Site

Increase the connection limit if limited by the host (open file limit of operating system) – Dashboard Site

Increase timeout setting of php (max_execution_time set to 5 minutes) –Dashboard Site

Disable aborting the request processing if the users closes the site (ignore_user_abort in php.ini) – Dashboard Site Hosting

Before choosing a hosting provider for your Dashboard be sure to check the Hosting Compatibility doc for any known issues.